# Customize Appendix numbering in memoir class

Tags: memoir

In memoir class how can I  have numbered appendices (APPENDIX 1 instead of APPENDIX B) both in the body of the document and in ToC? I have read the memoir user manual and could not find how

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `\renewcommand*\cftappendixname{Appendix~}` and `\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}` you can get the desired result.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand*\cftappendixname{Appendix~} % adds the word Appendicx in the toc
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Regular Chapter}
\appendix
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}} % Changes the numbering format from alph to arabic
\chapter{Appendix Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you leandriis, I had also put the \renewcommand before the \appendix statement.